# Cannot find the requested object when using X509Certificate class in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I was trying to extract certain properties from the certificate that was downloaded from corporate web site. The code I used is as below

```
X509Certificate cert = newX509Certificate(certByteArray, "pass");
MessageBox.Show(cert.Subject);
```

In executing the constructor on the Windows phone device and in emulator I get the bug as below

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException was unhandled by user code
   HResult=-2146885623
   Message=Cannot find the requested object.

  Source=mscorlib
   StackTrace:
        at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
        at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._QueryCertBlobType(Byte[] rawData)
        at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
        at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(Byte[] rawData, String password)
        at ChkCertificateApp.MainPage.btnCertifcateChk_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
        at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
        at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        at System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Control ctrl, EventArgs e)
        at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
   InnerException:
```

Please let me know what could be the issue and how to work around it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you load the certByteArray?

Comment: I got converted the Base 64 string to byte array and loaded that in CERT object